# Trouble making a calculator that can tell me the fraction and decimal form of the quotient of two numbers in C

Tags: c, math

Write a program that will allow a user to multiply and divide pairs of integer fractions and provide the resulting fraction and the decimal representation as a double with 2 decimal places.

I'll put some code I've tried below

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void) {

    int a, b, c, d, g, h, j, k;
    double e, f, l, m, n, o;

    //lets get our inputs//
    printf("Whats the first numerator:");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);

    printf("whats the first denominator(cannot be zero):");
    scanf_s("%d", &b);

    printf("whats the second numerator:");
    scanf_s("%d", &c);

    printf("whats the second denominator(cannot be zero):");
    scanf_s("%d", &d);  

    //calulate the division
    (__int64)e = (a / b);
    (__int64)l = (d / c);
    (__int64)m = e * l;
    //calculate the multiplication
    (__int64)f = (__int64)(a / b) * (__int64)(c / d);
    //im just gonna display the actual value of numerator * numerator 
    g = (a * c);
    //same for the denominator
    h = (b * d);
    //handled the fraction for multiplying so now its time to make the keep change flip

    j = (a * d);
    k = (b * c);

    printf("\n(%d/%d) / (%d/%d): the resulting fraction is %d/%d\nthe decimal representation is %.2f\n", a, b, c, d, j, k, m);

    printf("\n(%d/%d) * (%d/%d): the resulting fraction is %d/%d\nthe decimal representation is %.2f\n\n", a, b, c, d, g, h, f);

    return(0);

}
```

So what I'm pretty sure is happening is that I'm going from a 4 byte value to an 8 byte value by turning an integer into a double, but still I don't know how to cast it into a larger byte size, but Visual Studio says this `(__int64)` fixes it. Still my output for the fractions works but my decimals always appear as 0.00 which is because the value is lost when the cast value increases from 4 bytes to 8 bytes. (If I'm wrong about any of this please correct my understanding so I can be better at comp sci in general.)

Comment: Tip: to best see `double` that may be very small or large, use `"%e"` or `"%g"`.  There are more informative than `"%f"`.

Comment: Perhaps a good starting point is to use more meaningful variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dividing two integers, the result is the integer quotient. Any remainder is discarded. So, for example the code

```
int a = 7;
int b = 2;
int c = a / b;
double d = a / b;
```

will set `c` to 3.

It will also set `d` to 3. That's because the division is performed as integer division, and then the result is converted to a `double`.

To get the correct value for `d`, you need to cast one or both of the integers to a `double`. For example

```
double d = (double)a / b;
double d = a / (double)b;
double d = (double)a / (double)b;
```

will all set `d` to 3.5

So my suggestion is that you introduce two more variables to hold the fractions as `double` values and then do the multiplication and division:

```
//compute the fractions as doubles
double fraction1 = (double)a / (double)b;
double fraction2 = (double)c / (double)d;

//multiply the fractions
f = fraction1 * fraction2;

//divide the fractions
m = fraction1 / fraction2;
```

Comment: Converting to `double` and doing the multiplication as `double` will lose precision (53 bits vs 64).  I suspect OP is not concerned about that though.

Answer (score 1):

```
(__int64)f = (__int64)(a / b) * (__int64)(c / d);
```

This is where the issue is..

Firstly, learn to use standard notations and not Microsoft specific such as (__int64) which is effectively same as long long int but may need to be exclusively replaced so on standard toolchains. Secondly, you're typecasting a double to an int and then wondering where the decimal point has gone. Also `%d` is used for integers. Had you not typecasted to integer, still it wouldn't have taken the decimal value.

Such questions attract downvotes. I would suggest you to debug your code using a debugger first. Good luck :)

The code is as simple as this btw,

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(argc,argv)
const char** argv;
{
    int numer1 = 0;
    int denom1 = 0;
    int numer2 = 0;
    int denom2 = 0;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d ",&numer1,&denom1,&numer2,&denom2);    //don't forget zero logic
    double frac1 = (double)numer1/(double)denom1;
    double frac2 = (double)numer2/(double)denom2;
    printf ("Whatever you want to print....");
return 0;
}
```

Also learn to use [good nomenclature](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/01/30/how-to-choose-good-names/)

Comment: I recommend to move the non-answer part into a comment. You are aware that you can comment on your own posts, aren't you?

Comment: Actually typecasting doesn't do anything here except making the program ill-formed. It's unfortunate that Visual Studio compiler accepts it. The problem happens on the division itself, which operates on integers already.

Answer (score 1):

First, this:

```
(__int64)e = (a / b)
```

doesn't compile in a more standard-compliant compiler (even if `__int64` is supported there). You are casting a `double` variable to `__int64` and getting an rvalue, which can't be written to. I don't know what Visual Studio transforms this code into, but you shouldn't write like this.

Second, in that same code snippet you have `a/b`, which is *integer* division. It preserves quotient and throws away the remainder, effectively rounding the ratio to zero. This is your main problem. You should perform divisions with floating-point variables instead, or casting your integers to a floating-point type (e.g. `double`).

Answer (score 0):

Given fractions `a/b` and `c/d`:

The `a / b` in `double e = (a / b)` is *integer* division.  The quotient's fractional remainder is lost.

I'd recommend to perform the fraction multiplication using integer math only.

`a/b × c/d` --> `(a*c)/(b*d)`

See also [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations)

```
long long gcd(long long n, long long m) {
  while (n) {
    long long remainder = m % n;
    m = n;
    n = remainder;
  }
  return m;
}

  ...
  long long product_num = (long long)a * c;
  long long product_den = (long long)b * d;

  // At this point, code could simplify the product by looking for a common factor.
  long long common = gcd(product_num, product_den);
  if (common) {
    product_num /= common;
    product_den /= common; 
  }

  printf("The resulting fraction is %lld/%lld\n", product_num, product_den);
  printf("The decimal representation is %g\n", 1.0*product_num/product_den);
```

Note: `a/b ÷ c/d` is the same as `a/b × d/c`.

---

Comment: @JXN `long long` is an integer type of at least 64 bits.  Available since C99 (20 years ago).  Substitute with `__int64` is using an old C compiler.